# Connect Linux to specific WLAN Access Point

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspbian

In my vicinity are 2 WiFi access points with the same SSID (and on the same LAN). The signal strength of one is rather stable, while the other one is fluctuating. This causes devices like my phone to constantly hop from one AP to the other.

Can I set up Linux (specifically Raspbian) so that it will connect to only one of the two AP's, and stay connected to that, e.g. by specifying the MAC address?

Answer (score 1):

If you use WPA-supplicant, you can add a preferred BSSID (MAC address) to a network configuration. The [example wpa_supplicant configuration file](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) has all the gory details (search for `bssid:` on that page).

If you use a GUI (but you did not mention which one) this option might or might not be available.